# Is $f$ always positive if $f'>0$, $f''<0$?

Tags: calculus, economics

Is functions $f$ always positive if $f'>0$ and $f''<0$?

I intuitively can think that this is true but I want more details about the reason why this satisfies or not.

Thank you.

Comment: Consider $f(x) = -e^{-x}. f'(x) = e^{-x} > 0$ and $f''(x) = -e^{-x} < 0$ but $f$ is always negative.

Comment: I guess the conditions imply that $\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=-\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the counterexample $f(x)= - \frac{1}{x}$ defined on $(0, \infty)$?

Answer (score 1):

If you take $f(x) = - e^{-x} + 2$ it has both positive and negative values and $f’(x) > 0$ and $f’’(x)< 0$